# Did the Catholic Church justify castration with the "castri" choirs?

Tags: catholicism, sin, historic-customs

I was listening to a recent the [Art of Manliness podcast](https://open.spotify.com/episode/3MrRmIsJaVL0Gt7DhZWiba?si=NW_yfaURRn-0Lypy5NZSlw), they were talking about the castrati which I'd never heard of before, although it did come up once here.

Did the Catholic Church turn a blind eye to the practice of castrating boys to for choirs?  It seemed pretty barbaric from the podcast.  This might be a mental stretch over a millenia, but if one of the things keeping Origen from being canonized was because he castrated himself, wasn't castration (or any mutilation) thought of as a sin at the time?

Comment: The consensus of the scholars seems to be that this was a malicious rumour about Origen, possibly started by Demetrios, the Bishop of Alexandria, a prosecutor of Origen.

Comment: It seems to be a growing trend recently to use countertenors who sing in the range of alto or mezzo soprano.  But they [don't seem to be castrated](http://www.andreasschollsociety.org/biography.htm).  For examples, see a comparison of Handel's *Ombra Mai Fu* sung by a [countertenor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BWgISsML2BI) (starts at 1:29) compared with a [mezzo-soprano](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3jpGhODsmI) (starts at 0:42).  The latter is only one semitone higher. 
 More at [my question](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/119112/10162) to Music.SE.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though castration was forbidden under canon law, meaning that the official rule of the church was that castrati were not to be created on purpose (surgeons were even occasionally excommunicated for castration). As a sort of loophole, the boys presenting themselves to sing castrato in churches claimed to have been maimed through accident (even though most of them likely were not). But, Pope Clement VIII liked the way castrati sounded and semi-endorsed the practice by refusing to lift the ban on female singers in churches. In my opinion, a ridiculous- and highly imprudent tactic: it almost certainly would lead to and did lead to more castrations. But, Popes can make bad prudential judgements without the Church officially endorsing the evil that comes out of it. We see this in things like Amoris Laetitia, where Francis seems to make bad prudential judgements relating to how "re"married couples are to be received pastorally, which almost certainly leads to an abuse of the Eucharist. But there is no official endorsement of Eucharistic abuse.

Pope Leo XIII, bless that man, banned the hiring of castrato singers to churches, finally doing the thing required to put a stop to this disgusting practice. I am struck by the parallels with the modern world, which pushes parents to chemically castrate their little boys for the same "upward mobility" that came with parenting a successful castrato.

[Source](https://www.religioustolerance.org/rcccast.htm)

Comment: Can you add  the particular canon that castration was forbidden under Canon Law? It would improve your post.

Comment: Other sources also say canon law forbade it, but I am having a hard time finding this.

Comment: I did find that canon 1 of nicea forbids the admittance of willfully castrated males to the clergy, but that's not quite the same.

Comment: True but it implies that the Church was against the practice.